# Templates with generic classes

Tags: c++, arrays, templates

So recently i was working on templates got this issue that arrays may give errors when used with generic classes because compilers need to know what variable type and how many elements are required for an array at compile time. The information is necessary to allocate memory for the array. 
however i also came to know that information regarding templates are themselves understood at compile time itself? 
so shouldn't the compiler may know now how much space is required by the array and work without any issue?

```
template <class T>
class StudentRecord
{
private:
    const int size = SIZE;
    T grades[5];
    int studentId;
public:
    void setGrades(T* input);
    void setId(int idIn);
    void printGrades();
};

int main()
{
//StudentRecord is the generic class
StudentRecord<int> srInt();
srInt.setId(111111);
int arrayInt[SIZE]={4,3,2,1,4};
srInt.setGrades(arrayInt);
srInt.printGrades();
```

the error I am getting: 
error: request for member ‘setId’ in ‘srInt’, which is of non-class type ‘StudentRecord()’
     srInt.setId(111111);

Comment: `StudentRecord<int> srInt();` is parse as declaring a function called `srInt` returning a student record. Remove the `()` or use `{}` instead.

Comment: the question isn't even similar to the one being marked! i asked for something else...